# Existe um git hook para quando uma nova tag é criada?

Tags: git

Temos 3 ambientes: DEV, STAGE e PRD. O deploy em STG e PRD são feitos por tag criadas no git do projeto, ou seja, se quiser subir uma nova versão do sistema em STG, deve-se antes de fazer o push para o repositório, criar uma nova tag para que esta seja selecionada na pipeline de deploy. Após a versão ser validada, a mesma tag é subida em PRD.

O problema é que nos microservices - construídos em NodeJS - que dou e já dei suporte, a grande maioria (95%) não tem a `"version"` no `package.json` atualizada de acordo com a última tag criada. Essa informação de versão do projeto é importante para os *healthchecks* e *logs* dos MS.

Exemplo: Teve um projeto que tinha sua última tag `3.25.0`, mas a versão no `package.json` ainda era a padrão definida para todo inicio de projeto:

```js
{
  ...
  "version": "1.0.0", // provavelmente, nenhum dev nunca atualizou
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
  ...
```

Usamos a lib [Husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) para trabalhar em cima dos Git Hooks, como por exemplo os hooks `commit-msg` para fazer lint das mensagens de commit **durante o commit** e `pre-push` para executar os testes de unidade antes de fazer o **push para o repositório**.

A minha ideia é automatizar o processo de atualização de versão do projeto **toda vez que uma tag nova for criada**, porém não encontrei na documentação do husky um git hook para isso. Existe algum **git hook para criação de tag?**

---

Para o meu caso, eu criei esse script para automatizar a atualização de versão usando o `npm version` e quero que ele execute esse script toda vez que uma tag nova for criada.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

echo "==============================================="
echo "Update for new project git tag..."

latest_tag=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)

# verifica se existe ao menos uma tag
if [ -n "$latest_tag" ]; then
  # atualiza o package.json com a última tag criada.
  current_version=$(node -pe "require('./package.json').version")

  echo "Current project version: $current_version"
  echo "Last tag created: $latest_tag"

  # atualiza com comando do npm
  npm version "$latest_tag" --allow-same-version

  echo "Project version up to date"
fi

echo "==============================================="
```